# How to print a timestamp in a human readable format in SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, timestamp

I need to print a date in SQLite like this "24-03-2011 10:45:00", for now I only can print the date.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> database = sqlite3.connect('basedadosteste.db')
>>> cursor = database.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT date('now');")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00BC0710>
>>> results = cursor.fetchall()
>>> for entry in results:
...     print entry
...
(u'2011-03-25',)
>>>
```

Can someone give me a clue on how to do this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date` only gives you the date, hence the name. If you want the date and time, you have to use `datetime`.

And if you want to format the date, you can use `strftime` - either in the SQL command, or in Python. See the [sqlite3 date docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

This would work:

```
SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', 'now');
```